# SQLite showing exponential number instead of 0

Tags: sql, database, pandas, sqlite

### Data

I have a pandas DataFrame with several columns. One of them is a description, stored as an `object` and another one is the total amount for that description, which is stored as `float64`. Similar to this:

```
   id    desc amount
12345 Item 1A   15.9
12345 Item 2N   -3.9
12345 Item 1A   2.99
12345 Item  3  -5.15
12345 Item  3  -9.84
```

Using sqlalchemy I connect to the database and export the DataFrame using `to_sql`:

```
con = sqlalchemy.create_engine("sqlite:///database.db")
df.to_sql(name = "table1", con = con, dtype = {"amount": sqlalchemy.Float()})
```

### Problem

In the database, I execute the following query to get the total amount paid to that ID:

```
SELECT id, SUM(amount) AS 'TOTAL PAID' FROM table1 GROUP BY ID;
```

The database returns the following:

```
   id            TOTAL PAID
12345 -5.35510483179458e-10
```

The correct result would be:

```
   id TOTAL PAID
12345          0
```

I've checked and the column `amount` in the database does have the correct amounts. I think this might relate to the datatype used, but I am not sure. It happens to all IDs that the result is 0. IDs with a different result in the SUM function are displayed fine. As that column refers to money, I only need it to store two digits after the decimal point.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f4b31b176e3f9a90c38f4961f8e6d70b) you can find one of the records showing the problem.

### Question (TL;DR)

Why is SQLite showing an exponential number instead of 0 as the result of the aggregate function? How can I get the expected result?

#### Edit

When using the SUM function, it is not showing only that exponential number. It is showing several other exponential numbers for different IDs. There are some IDs which the total sum is 0 as well, but they are not affected. There is nothing diferent between the affected ones and the unaffected.

Comment: It's because you're usng floats.  Floats are approximations, not infinitely accurate miracles.  Search the web about floats and it's approximation nature *(which is true in every language that uses floats, not just SQL)*, don't just use them blindly, for monetary values you should most likely be using Decimals, they have a more limited range of possible values, but they're exact, not approximations.  *(Just for clarity, your result is -0.0000000005, that's as good as damnit zero, bar the rounding error introduced by using floats.)*

Comment: Thanks, @MatBailie.

Comment: Simply put if you want precise decimal, use decimal with scale and precision.  If you're dealing with extremely large or small numbers where precision isn't as important as size/performance, then use float.  Example how many atoms are there in the universe; good use for float.  distance between sub atomic particles again float.  Currency... use decimal.

Comment: The code works fine and returns `0`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e3b9fc5aac3883e171cdce971a76f5e0

Comment: @forpas check here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f4b31b176e3f9a90c38f4961f8e6d70b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQLite a data type like `FLOAT64` has `REAL` affinity as it is explained in [3.1. Determination Of Column Affinity](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#determination_of_column_affinity), so precision errors may occur.
Even in MySql the same precision error would happen with the data type `REAL`: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5Q5j3tnMnFieW9UHyMfFhK/0

In your case you would need a data type like `DECIMAL(12,2)` but it is not available in SQLite.

If you want a workaround, assuming that all values have max 2 digits after the decimal point then multiply each value by `100` and convert the result to an `INTEGER` which provides better accuracy. Then sum the values and divide by `100.0`:

```
SELECT id, 
       SUM(CAST((100 * amount) AS INTEGER)) / 100.0 AS [TOTAL PAID] 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY ID;
```

Or use the function `ROUND()`:

```
SELECT id, 
       ROUND(SUM(amount), 2) AS [TOTAL PAID] 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY ID;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=96b30dc31c50a6033e3a3f1e745c6e9f).
Results:

```
>    id | TOTAL PAID
> ----: | ---------:
> 12345 |          0
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

From [SQLite documentation - Representation Of Numbers](https://sqlite.org/src4/doc/trunk/www/decimal.wiki) :

> SQLite4 makes no distinction between integer and floating point numbers

That means that the engine will incurr in precision errors if you use any floating point value when computing a sum... and this is your case. There's no way around this in SQLite, unless you enforce all values are `INTEGER`. The SQLite engine won't enforce it for you, though. You would need to switch to another engine to fix this, unfortunately.

Comment: Why not just use `DECIMAL(9,2)`, for example?

Comment: @MatBailie There is no DECIMAL data type in SQLite: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: @forpas - I don't use SQLite so I'll trust you.  But that document does mention `DECIMAL(10,5)` with a `NUMERIC` affinity in section `3.1.1. Affinity Name Examples`  *(And it does appear to work in your fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=cf88f456757b293db529617b96744200 )*

Comment: @MatBailie exactly. Even if a data type like ABC is used (it is allowed), the affinity is NUMERIC and the result is correct: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3272066195b49585aaffcb505cb475c0

Comment: @forpas look at this example, which is the one giving me the error: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f4b31b176e3f9a90c38f4961f8e6d70b